# static function with PowerMockRunner

Tags: junit4, powermock

I have a function where i am getting data from cache instance which i need to mock

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSON(String identityAction) {
        IdentityActions identityActions = IdentityActionsCache.getInstance().getIdentityActionsByName(identityAction);


        List<RequestCategoryView> requestCategoryViews= identityActions.getReqCategory().getReqCategoryViews();
        for (RequestCategoryView requestCategoryView : requestCategoryViews) {
        ...
        }
        return null;
    }
```

IdentityActionsCache class

```
public static IdentityActionsCache getInstance() {
        if(null == singleton) {
            singleton = new IdentityActionsCache();
            singleton.init();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

public IdentityActions getIdentityActionsByName(String actionName){
    xyz
    return result;
}
```

Junit with powermock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({IdentityService.class, IdentityActionsCache.class})
public class IdentityServiceTest  {

@InjectMocks
IdentityService identityService;



 @Test
    public void getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSONTest() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result;
        try {
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(IdentityActionsCache.class);
            when(ServiceLocator.findService("workflowConfigDataService")).thenReturn(workflowConfigDataService);

            IdentityActions identityActions = new IdentityActions();

when(IdentityActionsCache.getInstance().getIdentityActionsByName(action)).thenReturn(identityActions);

            result = identityService.getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSON(action);


            assertTrue(result.equals(1l));
        } catch (ALNTApplicationException e) {
            assertFalse(false);
        } 
    }
}
```

I am not able to mock IdentityActionsCache.getInstance().getIdentityActionsByName(action) getting Null pointer

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.alnt.idm.user.identity.services.IdentityServiceTest.getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSONTest(IdentityServiceTest.java:70)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you needed to mock both a static and instance call

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({IdentityService.class, IdentityActionsCache.class})
public class IdentityServiceTest  {

    @InjectMocks
    IdentityService identityService;

    @Test
    public void getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSONTest() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result;
        try {
            //Arrange

            //...other members missing

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
            when(ServiceLocator.findService("workflowConfigDataService"))
                .thenReturn(workflowConfigDataService);

            IdentityActions identityActions = new IdentityActions();
            IdentityActionsCache cacheMock = mock(IdentityActionsCache.class); //instance mock
            when(cacheMock.getIdentityActionsByName(action)).thenReturn(identityActions);

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(IdentityActionsCache.class);
            when(IdentityActionsCache.getInstance()).thenReturn(cacheMock); //static call returns instance

            //Act
            result = identityService.getDuplicateCheckNotificationJSON(action);

            //Assert
            assertTrue(result.equals(1l));
        } catch (ALNTApplicationException e) {
            assertFalse(false);
        } 
    }
}
```